# Trying to run a procedure inside After insert trigger , even though procedure run for 10 mins last row updated time is same as 1st row

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join, triggers

Inside the trigger ,I'm trying populate multiple tables and trying to get start and end time of each table population , when run normally it takes 4 mins to populate table so start and end time has 4 mins difference.
But when triggered by populating it's trigger table it's showing start and end time same as triggered time ,but my table is getting populated

Table name:Tableupdatestatus

Expected Result

TableName:  Start time:       Endtime
XYZ:  03-05-2024 10:30:00:   03-05-2024 10:34:00

Actual Result in trigger

TableName:  Start time:         Endtime
XYZ:  03-05-2024 10:30:00:   03-05-2024 10:30:00

Comment: *Actual Result in trigger* You must use `SYSDATE()` function.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is by design.

From the MySQL manual:

> Functions that return the current date or time each are evaluated only
> once per query at the start of query execution. This means that
> multiple references to a function such as NOW() within a single query
> always produce the same result. (For our purposes, a single query also
> includes a call to a stored program (stored routine, trigger, or
> event) and all subprograms called by that program.) This principle
> also applies to CURDATE(), CURTIME(), UTC_DATE(), UTC_TIME(),
> UTC_TIMESTAMP(), and to any of their synonyms.

You'll find the reference on [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/date-and-time-functions.html), but you'll need to scroll down.